# error while creating a MoveIt package

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm at the second last step to complete my MoveIt package for an Epson C3-A601S robot.
( READ: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot Step 3.1)
Unfortunately I've stumbled on an error (I am not talking about the naming conventions):

```
wim@wim-laptop:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config  moveit_planning_execution.launch 
WARNING: Package name "epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
WARNING: Package name "epsonURDF_gripper" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
... logging to /home/wim/.ros/log/88aa3c70-eb61-11e5-9540-e0b9a546b0ae/roslaunch-wim-laptop-11096.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 730, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 702, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 666, in _recurse_load
    val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 587, in _include_tag
    inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 325, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 141, in _find
    source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 184, in _find_executable
    full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: [epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config]
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/wim/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Does anyone know who has had the same error or could tell me how I could prevent it?

Kind regards,

Wim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229224/error-while-creating-a-moveit-package/) by [wimvda](https://answers.ros.org/users/26297/wimvda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main error is here:

> ```
> ResourceNotFound: [epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config]
> ```

`roslaunch` cannot find that package in your workspace. Some things to check:

1. is there actually a package called `epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config` in your `catkin_ws/src`?
2. make sure you're using the *package name*, which does not necessarily need to be the same as the name of the *directory*
3. have you (re)built your workspace after adding the `epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config` package to it?
4. make sure there are no typos in `epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config` (note that Linux is case sensitive)

Easy check:

```
rospack find epsonURDF_gripper_moveit_config
```

should return the location of your package. If it doesn't, `roslaunch` won't be able to find it either.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wimvda](https://answers.ros.org/users/26297/wimvda/) on 2016-03-16**:
Hi,

I have found the error.
The square brackets needed to be removed in the launch file. This was the 'stupid' problem. My bad.
Thanks anyway for the quick reply!